# Making a copy of an Overleaf file removes comments?

Tags: overleaf, comments

My supervisor made some changes to my Overleaf report. Before working through them, I decided to make a copy of the file for easy future reference (if required). However, now when I go onto the copied file, none of the comments have been copied over!

I also encounter this problem in the original file when I cut a block of text (that has comments in it) to another location - the comments simply disappear. Pressing 'undo' returns the text, but not the comments. This is very frustrating as I seem to have lost a lot of changes simply due to cutting and pasting. Version histories do not contain the comments either.

Is there any way to get them back? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you contacted the Overleaf Helpdesk about this? I hear the LaTeX *fu* of their support staff is really good.

Comment: Is it about copying one single file or copying the entire project folder?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(I'm on support staff at Overleaf.)

It's not 100% clear from your question if you're asking about copying an entire project (often times Overleaf users colloquially refer to this as "copying the file" when in fact they are copying the entire project), or if you're copying only a single file within a project. Either way, yes, comments and tracked changes are not transferred when you copy a project or copy a single file within a project.

More broadly, when copying an entire project, the project's history, chat, track changes, and sharing settings are empty in the resulting new project. Effectively only the project's source files are copied into a new project, and the compiler engine and main file settings are transferred.

For more information, see [Copying a Project: Copied Projects](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Copying_a_project#Copied_projects)

---

As for comment and tracked change positions being lost when copying and pasting large chunks of text, or undoing/redoing changes that involve large chunks of text: this can happen in rare cases, unfortunately. Usually our system catches this and in most cases our support team can restore a previous snapshot of the comments and tracked changes.

If you'd like to see if this is possible, please write to us at support@overleaf.com with the following information:

- the URL of the affected project;
- the name(s) of file(s) in the project where you require track changes restored;
- the date and time that the problem occurred; and
- the time zone you were in when the problem happened.

We will then check our systems to see if a previous snapshot can be restored.

Comment: Thank Paul, that makes sense. I wonder if this is something Overleaf is planning on adding functionality to in the future? On the surface it seems like a simple fix, but is probably more complex under the hood!

Comment: @ddm_ingram you're welcome! It's not something we have definite plans to change, but we have had similar requests. (Though it should be said that many users also expect that copying a project does _not_ transfer this information. So if we make a change here, I suspect we might structure it so that both options are available somehow.) I'll make a note for our team to consider this in our internal tracking of these requests, thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @PaulGessler can also confirm I've tried to find this functionality to keep track of different iterations of feedback (making duplicates of .tex files to track progression and change). Would make more sense if I was also using .git integration I guess!

Comment: The answer focuses on copying the entire project folder while the question seems to focus on the copying of a single file in one single project folder.

Comment: @HighGPA I had assumed I had understood the question correctly based on the fact that the question author accepted the answer not long after I wrote the answer, but I've added some more information for the other cases now. Hope it helps.

Comment: @PaulGessler Thanks for clarifying.